# getResource isn't working exported in a jar

Tags: java, file, resources

So getResource does not work in a jar, or as I have it in my code it is returning the children of the file to null when I ask to list its files. In eclipse it works perfectly fine. I need it as a file, to list its children which are more files.

The / is relating to the class folder I have added.

Here is the block of code:

```
    try {
        mapFiles = (new File(LevelPickerScreen.class.getResource("/Maps").toURI())).listFiles();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It is better why it seems not to work, because it surely works if well configured. Can you explain how is your jar file structured? Is your Maps folder placed directly in the jar or in a sub-folder?

Answer (score 2):

`getResource` works perfectly well - but you're then calling the `File` constructor, and the resource *doesn't* exist as a `File`. It's not a file - it's a resource within a jar file.

I suspect you'll find it hard to get it to list the resources within the jar file in this way, too - you *could* load the jar file separately, but it would probably be simpler just to automate listing all of the children as part of your build procedure, and then drop a file into the jar file as `/Maps/maps.txt` which contains a list of the map names. You can then load each of them in turn using `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` - but *don't* try to use the `File` API with it.

Comment: As for loading the jar file separately, you can use a ZipUtil. jars are basically zips

Comment: @k_g: Yes, it's just a but of a faff. I reckon listing the files beforehand would be simpler.